# Data breakpoint in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging, breakpoints

In MATLAB, is it possible to set a data breakpoint on a specific variable as it is done in Visual Studio? I could not find anything online and in the manual.

To be clear: a data breakpoint stops execution and enters debug mode when that variable changes value anywhere in the code, not only on one specific line.

Comment: Can you wrap your variable as a private property in a class with getter and setter functions? A breakpoint could be conveniently attached to these functions, and any access to the variable should go through them.

Answer (score 4):

Update: April 28th 2023

If your variable is a property of a class you could change the `SetAccess` to `private` (or `protected`), and then have it update via a class method then you can trap when it changes using conditional breakpoints.

I appreciate this suggestion only works for classes and is a significant change to a large code base, but its the only fool proof way that I know of to capture when a variable changes.

FYI: I have done this on a large and complex code base, luckily the class variable names throughout were always consistent and we had enough test cases to capture all locations where the property was set.

**Update to add example code**

Assuming your original code is something like (18th May 2023):

```
function main()
  % initialise
  refStruct.variableWantToCheck = 10;
  % this variable is used elsewhere
  refStruct = subFunction ( refStruct );
end

function refStruct = subFunction ( refStruct )
  % the variable gets changed
  refStruct.variableWantToCheck = refStruct.variableWantToCheck + 1;
  % the variable is passed to another function
  refStruct = otherFunction ( refStruct );
end


function refStruct = otherFunction ( refStruct )
  % the variable gets changed (again)
  refStruct.variableWantToCheck = refStruct.variableWantToCheck - 1;
  % call another function (example not shown here)
  refStruct = etcFunction ( refStruct );
end
```

If your source variable is a class instead of a struct, like below

```
class refClass < handle
  properties
    variableWantToCheck = [];
  end
  methods
     % constructor
     function obj = refClass ( var )
       obj.variableWantToCheck = var;
     end
     % this example is using the "set method"
     function set.variableWantToCheck ( obj, var )
       obj.variableWantToCheck = var;
     end
  end
end
```

Then you change your original code, in the main:

```
function main()
  % initialise the class instead of the struct.
  refVariable = refClass ( 10 );
  % this variable is used elsewhere
  % you can change the call here as the class is a handle class, it doesnt need to be passed back out of the subFunction.  This can be repeated in the other functions as well.
  subFunction ( refVariable );
end
```

You can set a conditional breakpoint in the set function to capture when the variable is modified to something of interest.

---

It does its called [conditional breakpoints](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html#buvvmfu-1).

You can set them at the command line but its a lot easier to put them in interactively via the editor (right click on "-" next line number and select "Set Conditional Breakpoint"

Commandline:

```
dbstop in FUNCTION at LINENO if 'EXPRESSION'
```

Comment: Thanks. But That is not a data breakpoint. Yours is a conditional breakpoint on a specific line. I want to break when the value of a data is changed anywhere in the code not when a condition is met on a specific line. If you have a huge code a data breakpoint is useful to find quickly what messes up the value of the variable.

Comment: I know what you mean but I think its the closest you will get - as described [here in Mathworks information](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92448-how-can-i-watch-variables-using-the-matlab-debugger).

Comment: I know but for me it is completely different and knowing that in a line it changed value it is not gonna help me, I already know it. I want to know in which line it changed values, easy thing to do in visual studio.Thanks anyway

Comment: @millemila - updated answer - don't know if it helps your use case or not.

Comment: The idea to do this using class properties is good. You only need to create a setter method, there's no need to make the property private. If you make a setter method, it will always be run when the variable is updated, so you can set a breakpoint in it.

Comment: @matlabgui, could you please provide a working minimal code example that explains how that is implemented?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think thats possible but you can achieve the same using conditional breakpoint. Just set what can be achieved just before a breakpoint. when you right click on the breakpoint, there will be where you can enter your condition.