# Is there really no option for data breakpoint in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, breakpoints

I do not want a conditional breakpoint, but a data breakpoint for a variable. If that variable value changes anywhere in the code then the debug stops at that location. The same thing a Data Breakpoint is handled in Visual Studio. I find nothing online, the closest thing is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281512/data-breakpoint-matlab-matlab) but it has no good answer.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a specific code example case where the conditional breakpoint described in the linked answer does not meet your needs.

Comment: You already know [the documentation page on break points](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html), because it was linked in the answer to the other question. That page lists all the possible ways to set break points. It does not list a way to break when a specific variable changes value, so this is not possible.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. You can draw attention to the other question by offering a bounty.